# Disable R-linting in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

In the picture below you can see a lot of linting-highlights e.g "Lines should not be more than 80 characters".

I'm trying to disable/modify these but I cannot figure out how. Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/rtvs/linting-r-code?view=vs-2017) guide I cannot find the path **Tools > Options > Text Editor > R > Lint**.

How do we change/disable this "help"?

Note, I'm using the R-extension by Yuki Ueda

[image]

Comment: Still searching a solution. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 27):

You might want to disable linting by setting the vscode setting `"r.lsp.diagnostics": false`.

Or you might want to customize the list of linters to be used by editing `~/.lintr` to effect globally or `{workspaceFolder}/.lintr` to effect project-wise. Read https://lintr.r-lib.org/articles/lintr.html#configuring-linters for the details of the lintr config file.

Comment: Had a similar issue to the OP - disabling diagnostics turned off several other useful features for me so I didn't go with this approach. But editing `.lintr` file worked great.

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur, the link is fixed.

Comment: can someone help to get rid of linters globally (for R files in vscodes) using `lintr`? thanks

Comment: This solution no longer seems to be enough (since few days ago).

Comment: Maybe it is related to the latest release of vscode-R with vscode-languageclient upgraded to 8.0.2. But I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @sindri_baldur, I experience the same. There is also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver/issues/570) on the matter.

Answer (score -3):

This can happen if the file is not save with a .R file name extension, including if you're editing a file that has not been saved.

When saving the file, test saving as different extensions and see if that solves it.

If this does not solve it, try disabling the R-extension and reloading to confirm that R-extension is causing the problem.

Comment: True that, but it does not answer the question, Stenemo. The Kun Ren's answer provides the right solution I reckon.